# Android Studio install ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, java

I try to install android studio on ubuntu machine. I download android studio zip file from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). I run `/android-studio/bin$ sh studio.sh` command on terminal, it says that `OpenJDK 6 is not supported. Please use Oracle Java or newer OpenJDK.` To fix this problem, I run `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`. But this way cannot solve my problem. What should I do?

Comment: what does `sudo update-alternatives --config java` return?

Comment: @Blackbelt no, it will not start AS either, he must need to install Oracle Java in Ubuntu

Comment: Download and install java manually. sudo apt-get... will not wok. Do some google search how to install Oracle JDK in ubuntu, there will be lot of articles.

Comment: @Blackbelt   /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   ,   /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   ,  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java. I already have them.

Comment: you have to select the last one, and it should work

Comment: I try it,  I get "'tools.jar' seems to be not in Android Studio classpath.Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE." error. I run "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64", but it doesn't work.

Comment: To install java , Follow this [link][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/a/88058

Comment: To install java , Follow this [link][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/a/88058

Answer (score 2):

try to install ORACLE JAVA 8 IN UBUNTU VIA PPA, this for ubuntu 15.04, 14.10, 14.04, 12.04 and 10.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

**EDIT**: 
This command will give you a list of alternative java options, which you will then be able select a JDK instead of JRE:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: After these commands, I get 'tools.jar' seems to be not in Android Studio classpath. Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE error.  I try export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64, but it doesn't work.

Comment: try also to restart your computer

Comment: I don't understand how it was solved.But I download android studio zip file again now, and run sh. it works, thanks your answer.

Answer (score 0):

first install java by using these commands.

```
wget --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz

sudo mkdir /opt/jdk

sudo tar -zxf jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/jdk

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java 100

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/javac 100
```

now these steps will install Android studio

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install android-studio
sudo /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

this will do.

Comment: On the last step I get "'tools.jar' seems to be not in Android Studio classpath.Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE." error. I run "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64", but it doesn't work.